# Jquery animated arc / circle drawing in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to find a solution to animating an arc / circle using jquery only - no HTML5 or CSS3, as this needs to work in IE 9.

I have found several jquery plugins, but none that work in IE 9.

http://blog.templatemonster.com/demos/how-to-build-jquery-animated-circle-statistics/demo/index.html

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circle-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-SVG-asPieProgress/

Is there a way to animate an arc using jquery only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animated circles example here

http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

Seems to work well.

I have tested this in IE9 and firefox, chrome and safari and looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? [Here is the JS.Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q73wbtfr/1/)

JQuery:

```
 $(function() {
  $(".circle1").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({top:"0", left:"0", width:"100px", height:"100px", opacity: 1}, 200);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({top:"50px", left:"50px", width:"0", height:"0", opacity: 1}, 200);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.circle1 {
    position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;
    width: 0px; height: 0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circle1"></div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you look at the two links in my original post, as long as you are not using IE, you will see what I am trying to do. I want to animate an arc of a circle, from 0 degrees round to a variable number.